# How to teleop PR2 arm in simulation?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed [Teleop PR2 arm in simulation](http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_simulator/Tutorials/Teleop%20PR2%20arm%20in%20simulation).

When I run:

```
  sam@sam:~/code/ros/manipulation/teleop_arms$ ./bin/teleop_pr2_arms_keyboard 
  Reading from keyboard
  ---------------------------
  Use 'WS' to forward/back
  Use 'AD' to left/right
  Use 'QE' to up/down
  sam@sam:~/code/ros/manipulation/teleop_arms$ ./bin/teleop_pr2_arms_keyboard 
  Reading from keyboard
  ---------------------------
  Use 'WS' to forward/back
  Use 'AD' to left/right
  Use 'QE' to up/down
```

But I can't control PR2 by press W,S,A,D,Q,E on this terminal.

How to fix it?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37980/how-to-teleop-pr2-arm-in-simulation?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-07-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try `roslaunch pr2_teleop_general pr2_teleop_general_keyboard.launch`

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0